# Candian citizen working for USA company staying in Canada

Tags: united-states, canada, self-employment, contractor

I am a Canadian citizen. What legalities do I need to follow if I take up a full time remote job offer from a company in USA? Also, how does the answer change if the job offer is in USA (remote) but i am working as independent contractor, not employee?

Do I need separate work visa?

Comment: Are you asking about how to be self-employed in Canada, or how to get a TN visa to move to the US?

Comment: I dont want to move to the US, I want to work remotely for a US employer/client, from my home in Canada. For this purpose, do i need a visa?

Comment: No, why would you. You'd be self-employed in Canada.

Comment: Thanks.  So my corporation will pay taxes to both IRS and CRA?

Comment: Why would you pay taxes to IRS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way most companies handle cross-border payroll is to attach the remote worker to a department already in that country for legal/financial purposes and then put them "on assignment" across the border. This avoids expensive and complicated paperwork, letting the company move the money internally (much simpler) and then make normal payment. Simplifies the employee's taxes too, obviously.

(I spent several years based in Boston but assigned to the Toronto lab.)

If there isn't already an office in that country to play this roll, companies may not even want to *try* to have people working remotely from another country. The overhead is just too high for a single individual.

I have no idea whether/how this is affected by being a contractor rather than employee.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, what Toronto lab? IBM?

Comment: Yep. XML, XSLT,  and related technologies.